# Wrapped AggregateException reports just first exception in ToString method

Tags: c#, aggregateexception

I get complete set of nested exceptions when I use `ToString()` method on `AggregateException` directly:

```
public void GreenTest()
{
    var ex = new AggregateException(new Exception("ex1"), new Exception("ex2"));

    ex.ToString()
        .Should()
        .Contain("ex1")
        .And
        .Contain("ex2");
}
```

The problem is I get only the first exception when the `AggregateException` is wrapped in another exception:

```
public void RedTest()
{
    var ex = new Exception("wrapper", new AggregateException(new Exception("ex1"), new Exception("ex2")));

    ex.ToString()
        .Should()
        .Contain("wrapper")
        .And
        .Contain("ex1")
        .And
        .Contain("ex2");
}
```

`ex2` isn't present in the resulting string. Is this a bug or some well-known feature of `AggregateException` class?

Answer (score 6):

I think not that this is a bug. More a normal behavior

The problem is that the [ToString()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/exception.cs,9ce1ff20e283169f) on `Exception` will not call the `ToString()` of the `innerException`, but the private `ToString(bool,bool)` method on the exception class itself.

So the overridden [ToString()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/AggregateException.cs,edb789d3a00adc00,references) method of the `AggregateException` is not called.

The [constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/AggregateException.cs,c3193c051cbb0f3b) of the AggregateException will set the innerException to the first exception passed to the constructor.

In your case this is `new Exception("ex1")`

Comment: You're right, but is this really intended and meaningful behavior? It's quite dangerous especially for logging of such exceptions - you just loose part of the exception. I'd say it's a bug :) I don't see any meaningful reason for this behavior.

Comment: @Buthrakaur I think not that this is a bug. You should not use the base Exception class. Use a custom one and provide an override of ToString() if you want to change the behavior

Comment: @Buthrakaur You should also note that the class Exception exits long time  before AggreagateException was implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the [reference source link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/AggregateException.cs,c3193c051cbb0f3b), I must endeavor to spend more time in that place.

Comment: For every Exception type I'm aware of, the ToString() method accessed from the base Exception.ToString() dumps the entirety of the information in the Exception... with the (ahem) exception of AggregateException.  The hugely valuable takeaway here for me is that casting the exception down to AggregateException so you can call its ToString() will dump all the aggregated exceptions.  (Still feels like a bug.)